# How to Inject external css style sheet into GWT Panel widget?

Tags: css, gwt, cssresource

How to inject CSS style sheet into one of my Vertical Panels in GWT ?

I have the following code

**MainPanelResources.java**

```
public interface MainPanelResources extends ClientBundle {

public interface MyMainPanelResourcesCss extends CssResource{
     public static final MainPanelResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(MainPanelResources.class);


 @Source("MainPanel.css")
 public CssResource css();
 }
}
```

**MainPanel.css**

```
@external .mainPanel {
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Comment: If you found your answer either close this question or post it as an answer. This helps keep the site "clean".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in Google Web Toolkit group, in **Basic CSS question** posted by **Mike Dee**
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/TaQNg9Koemk/YI9btAZnaMIJ